# Calling a block function in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays

I am trying to run a following Function

```
+(NSString *)responseFromQuery:(NSString *) queryString
{
    __block NSString *response;
    __block NSError *err = nil;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0),^{
        response = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:queryString] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            NSLog(@"%@",response);
             if (err != nil)
             {
                UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert!"
                                                                    message:@"An Error has occurred" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

                [alertView show];
                 return response;// = @"Error";
              }

            });
        });
   // return response;
}
```

I want to pass the value of response after executing the block, however instead it runs the last return first , how can i make the return expression within block to run. 
I am using this function in an NSObject Class
According to the debugging it never runs the `dispatch_async queue.`

Right now if i return it gives me error `"Control may reach at the end of non void block"`

Comment: dispatch_async is exactly that: asynchronous.  Use a synchronous call if you want control over when (or rather, in the order that) it executes

Comment: @CodaFi Can u elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fully understand the implementation and working of blocks in objective c i think you should  look into the following link, it explains quite a lot and it is put really simply.

[Objective C Blocks - Simple Understanding](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/understanding-objective-c-blocks/)

Answer (score 0):

because you are returning  `return response`;. because of you are returning response it is saying that "Control may reach at the end of non void block". you returning something means it is  non void block. directly return on last statement of method.

Comment: i am using this function in NSObject class, i have noticed that it actually never runs my dispatch_Async block. how can i do that?

Comment: How do you know it isn't executing the inner block?  Did you set a breakpoint, or are you relying on some kind of console output?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use dispatch_async and return the value inside the executed block at the same time. The *async* part of *dispatch_async* means the function will return immediately and will not wait for the block to finish executing. For this you would need *dispatch_sync* without the 'a'.

The problem you would have with that is that you are making a network request in your block and that could block your UI thread. I'm assuming this function is being called in the main thread.

If you want to make an asynchronous request and send the return value to the caller you can add a block parameter to your function where the sender of the message will be notified. The method would go from being:

```
+(NSString *)responseFromQuery:(NSString *) queryString;
```

To:

```
+ (void)responseFromQuery:(NSString *)queryString withBlock:(void (^)(NSString *result))block;
```

and when you have your response string you call:

```
block(response);
```

Comment: can you modify my code and also how to call this too? I am using this function of mine in an NSObject class to get response in my UIViewController class